# Add consumer failing

Tags: solidity, chainlink

I want to add consumers to an existing subscription but it's failing as only the owner can add the consumer I want to add Chainlink VRF in my NFT Marketplace and here I am creating NFTs in bulk so users can create as many tokens as they want hence do I need to create a subscription for each address or is there any other way to handle this?
Here's my code:

```
NFT.sol     
constructor(
        string memory _name,
        string memory _symbol,
        uint256 updateInterval,
        uint256 _winnerPercentage,
        uint64 subscriptionId,
        address vrfCoordinator
        )
        ERC721(_name, _symbol)
        VRFConsumerBaseV2(vrfCoordinator)
    {
        interval = updateInterval;
        lastTimeStamp = block.timestamp;
        winnerPercentage = _winnerPercentage;
        s_subscriptionId = subscriptionId;
        COORDINATOR = VRFCoordinatorV2Interface(vrfCoordinator);
        addSubscription();
    }
function addSubscription() internal   {
        COORDINATOR.addConsumer(s_subscriptionId, address(this));
    } 

Marketplace. sol

    function createToken(string memory name, string memory symbol, uint256 updateInterval, uint256 winnerPercentage, uint64 subscriptionId, address vrfCoordinator) public {
       address _address = address(new NFT(name, symbol, updateInterval,winnerPercentage, subscriptionId, vrfCoordinator));   
        uint256 count = 0;
       tokens[msg.sender].push(_address);
       CollectionAddresses.push(_address);
       count++;       
        emit TokenCreated(msg.sender, _address);
    }
Could you please help me with this? 
Thank you!
```

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, you could have a single contract handling all the RNG calls (so, no need to add consumers everytime you create a new contract), or make the marketplace contract the subscription owner and manage adding the newly created contracts as consumers there.

---

EDIT: Here is some example code for the second option :

```
Marketplace.sol 

 function createToken(
        string memory name,
        string memory symbol,
        uint256 updateInterval,
        uint256 winnerPercentage,
        uint64 subscriptionId,
        bytes32 keyHash,
        address vrfCoordinator
    ) public {
        address _address = address(new NFT(name, symbol, updateInterval, winnerPercentage, subscriptionId, address(this), keyHash, vrfCoordinator));
        uint256 count = 0;
        tokens[msg.sender].push(_address);
        CollectionAddresses.push(_address);
        count++;
        addNFTConsumer(subscriptionId, vrfCoordinator, _address);
        emit TokenCreated(msg.sender, _address);
    }
    function addNFTConsumer(uint64 subscriptionId, address coordinator, address tokenAddress) internal {
        coordinator.addConsumer(subscriptionId, tokenAddress);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the response!
I have made some changes to my NFT and Marketplace contract but I am not able to add the NFT addresses as a consumer from the Marketplace contract yet so can you please check my modified code and provide a suggestion to resolve the issue?

```
NFT.sol 

 address marketplaceOwner;
      constructor(
           string memory _name,
        string memory _symbol,
        uint256 _updateInterval,
        uint256 _winnerPercentage,
        uint64 _subscriptionId,
        address _marketplaceOwner,
        bytes32 _keyHash,
        address _vrfCoordinator

        )
        ERC721(_name, _symbol)
        VRFConsumerBaseV2(_vrfCoordinator)
    {
        interval = _updateInterval;
        lastTimeStamp = block.timestamp;
        winnerPercentage = _winnerPercentage;
        s_subscriptionId = _subscriptionId;
        marketplaceOwner = _marketplaceOwner;
        keyHash = _keyHash;
    }
   modifier onlyMarketplaceOwner {
        require(msg.sender == marketplaceOwner, "Only Marketplace owner can call this function");
        _;
    }
      function addConsumer() external {
    COORDINATOR.addConsumer(s_subscriptionId, address(this));
}
Marketplace.sol 

 function createToken(
        string memory name,
        string memory symbol,
        uint256 updateInterval,
        uint256 winnerPercentage,
        uint64 subscriptionId,
        bytes32 keyHash,
        address vrfCoordinator
    ) public {
        address _address = address(new NFT(name, symbol, updateInterval, winnerPercentage, subscriptionId, address(this), keyHash, vrfCoordinator));
        uint256 count = 0;
        tokens[msg.sender].push(_address);
        CollectionAddresses.push(_address);
        count++;
        emit TokenCreated(msg.sender, _address);
    }
    function callAddConsumer(address tokenAddress) public {
        NFT(tokenAddress).addConsumer();
    }
```

Comment: Hey! This is not an answer to your question. You should have added it as an edit to your original question or open a new question instead of posting it as an answer. Try to do that next time :)

To answer you though, your addConsumer() function should be in the marketplace contract directly, i edited my original answer with example code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I apologize for this and I will make sure to take care of it the next time!
Thanks again!

Comment: Hey @Foxxxe, I modified my code according to your suggestion but I am facing an error called: execution reverted
 "The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance."  while calling the CreateToken function. I have already added the Marketplace contract address as a Consumer to the subscription Management so could you please help me to figure out this issue?

Comment: @MahimaThacker the marketplace contract needs to be the subscription *owner*, not a mere consumer. You can transfer ownership of a subscription by calling `requestSubscriptionOwnerTransfer` from the current owner (presumably your address) and having your contract call `acceptSubscriptionOwnerTransfer` once that's done (so you'd need to write a new function in your contract for that)